# Nice and child processes

Tags: linux, process, nice

Can someone tell me what is the relationship between a specified `nice` level and child processes?

For example, if I have a default `nice` of `0`, and I start a script with `nice 5`, which in turn starts some child processes (in this case about 20 in parallel), what is the nice of the child processes?

Comment: Only the root user can decrease the niceness of a process, and the value is inherited by child processes in any sensible `fork` implementation.

Comment: @jw013 - For clarity, I am scripting, using `&` to spawn child processes, not using `c` & `fork`.

Comment: unless you are on a non-Unix/Linux OS, it's a fairly safe bet that your shell spawns background processes with `fork`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A child process inherits whatever `nice` value is held by the parent at the time that it is forked (in your example, `5`).

However, if the `nice` value of the parent process changes after forking the child processes, the child processes do not inherit the new `nice` value.

You can easily observe this with the monitoring tool `top`. If the `nice` field (NI) is not shown by default, you can add it by pressing `f` and choosing `I`. This will add the `NI` column to the `top` display.

`* I: NI         = Nice value`

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1937 root      20   0  206m  66m  45m S  6.2  1.7  11:03.67 X
```

Good information from `man 2 fork`

> fork()  creates  a new process by duplicating the calling process.  The new process, referred to as the child, is an exact duplicate of the calling process, referred  to  as  the  parent, except for the following points:
>
> - The  child has its own unique process ID, and this PID does not match
>   the ID of any existing process group (setpgid(2)).
> - The child's parent process ID is the same as the parent's process ID.
> - The child does not inherit its parent's memory locks (mlock(2), mlockall(2)).
> - Process resource utilizations (getrusage(2)) and CPU time counters (times(2)) are reset to zero in the child.
> - The child's set of pending signals is initially empty (sigpending(2)).
> - The child does not inherit semaphore adjustments from its parent (semop(2)).
> - The child does not inherit record locks from its parent (fcntl(2)).
> - The  child  does  not  inherit  timers from its parent (setitimer(2), alarm(2), timer_create(2)).
> - The child does not  inherit  outstanding  asynchronous  I/O  operations  from  its  parent (aio_read(3),  aio_write(3)),  nor  does it inherit any asynchronous I/O contexts from its parent (see io_setup(2)).