# How do I start a shell so that all processes run from within it and processes they run have low priority?

Tags: linux, shell, scheduling

I'd like to start a long, complex CPU and IO heavy command-line job to be done in background while I'm using the PC. It will hinder responsiveness of the system if I run it with normal priority. How do I start a shell (under which the job will be executed) the way all the processes ran from within it and processes they run would have low priority?

Comment: Possibly related: [Nice and child processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37896/nice-and-child-processes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute a command in a process with lower priority whether that command is a shell or your heavy command (which itself could also be a shell script), on Linux you can do:

```
nice ionice -c idle the-command and its arguments
```

`nice` is standard, `ionice` is Linux-specific.

To run some shell code, use `sh -c` as the command:

```
nice ionice -c idle sh -c '
  for i in foo bar; do
    heavycmd "$i" > "$i.log"
  done'
```

`nice` alone increases the niceness by `10`, you can specify a different increment with the `-n` option.

In the `zsh` shell, you can set the `bgnice` option (on by default when interactive) so that all commands run in background have their niceness increased by 5.

In the `(t)csh` shell, `nice` is a builtin which can also change the niceness of the shell (beware that the syntax is different from the `nice` standard command (`nice +10 cmd` to specify arbitrary niceness (not increment!)) and the default niceness is 4).

In shells that don't support changing their own niceness by themselves, you can use `renice` instead. Beware that [`renice -n 5 "$pid"` is currently required by POSIX to *decrease* the niceness of the process of id `$pid` by 5](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/), but that's not what happens in any implementation I know and is quite obviously a [bug](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1286) in the POSIX specification¹. In practice, it either sets the niceness to 5² or *increases* it by 5.

In practice, `renice -n 20 "$pid"` assuming the niceness was not negative in the first place would set the niceness to the highest value at least on Linux.

Note that `nice` (introduced in Unix V4 in the mid-70s) initially didn't take any number argument. A numeric argument was added independently in Unix V7 and in csh (BSD based on V6) but done differently. In V7, `nice -5 cmd` increased the niceness by 5 while in csh (as seen above), that would set it to `-5`. `renice` was initially from BSDs and was consistent with csh's `nice` (`renice +5 "$pid"` to set the niceness to 5).

That history explains why nowadays, outside of `csh`, `nice -5` increases niceness and `renice -5` decreases it. I suspect `-n` is a POSIX invention (like for `head -n`) introduced to get rid of the option names with leading `+` and to try and come with a clean API (niceness values are also not portable, so it makes more sense to deal with increments).

The I/O niceness of other arbitrary processes can also be changed with `ionice` and its `-p` option.

So from within the shell (Bourne-like shells here), you can change the niceness of the process that executed the shell interpreter with:

```
renice -n 20 "$$"
ionice -c idle -p "$$"
```

Or to change the niceness of the current subshell:

```
(
  pid=$(sh -c 'echo "$PPID"')
  renice -n 20 "$pid"
  ionice -c idle -p "$pid"

  # do stuff in the subshell with lower priority / higher niceness
)
```

In the `bash` shell, you can also get the current subshell pid with `$BASHPID` and in `zsh` with `$sysparams[pid]` (after `zmodload zsh/system`). Beware that the `ksh93` shell doesn't implement subshell environments with child processes, so the above would affect the niceness globally there.

---

<sup>¹
That was introduced in [SUSv3](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/renice.html), the [previous version](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/renice.html) (which also specified the original `renice` API (as obsolete)) correctly said that a positive value decreased the *priority*, not niceness</sup>

<sup>² like in the `util-linux` implementation. That is a [bug](https://marc.info/?l=util-linux-ng&m=156846960629603&w=2). [`-n` was added in 2009](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=7cfbafda9c484a8cadefc47ee115086e803d9391) for POSIX conformance, but maintainers failed to realise that `-n` takes an *increment* in the POSIX specification. The help message [since 2010](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=296351b0f112c821bffbe8ce7aa35d716251051d) does refer to an *increment*, but that's not what happens.</sup>